# Network traffic monitoring for each user

Tags: networking, server, multiple-monitors, network-manager, monitoring

There are several users in Ubuntu server using the network traffic. I need to monitor each users traffic usage. I used nethogs but apparently it gives me the answer for each process so when the user disconnects and connect again it opens a totally different row is created. Is there a way that I can filter this out or use another method or package to get the usage by each user. And I need it to be saved on the server I can't have a terminal open for this matter.

Btw, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04
Please feel free to ask me about other information that can help you give me an answer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Linux distributions generally do not monitor bandwidth on a per-user basis, so something bespoke will need to be set up with scripting and `iptables` commands. Does everyone who uses this server use the same set of limited ports? Or are you planning on tracking absolutely everything that is done?

Comment: thank you for responding. they do not use limited ports I need to monitor everything

Comment: In that case, you will need enterprise-grade server monitoring tools. Many are available with a free tier, though you’ll need to do the research to determine which one collects the metrics that you’re looking for. Each one has its own set of pros and cons.